# Android detecting USB DAC but Windows 10 not detecting it

Tags: windows, usb, android

I have a Yamaha PSR-E363, (Which has MIDI In And Out, And USB DAC) that when connected to an Android device, the cell phone detects MIDI In And Out, And the USB DAC as well. But when connected to my computer, there's no trace of any USB DAC.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Does the device manager show anything? Most likely you will see an entry with an yellow exclamation mark which means you have to install appropriate drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, Robert. The drivers were on the keyboard's download page. Thank you very much and Merry Christmas!

Yamaha PSR-E363 USB DAC Driver: https://es.yamaha.com/files/download/software/5/1359445/YSUSB_V204_Win.zip (Spanish link because on yamaha.com it's not working)